# Change url on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

When user clicked on A tag ( `<a href='showSomething.aspx?id=11&key=fixed'>Bring Something</a>` ) showSomethingPage.aspx will be shown with URL parameters. But I want to change URL from `showSomething.aspx?id=11&key=fixed` to `showSomething.aspx?key=fixed` in despite of shown the thing with id 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the ID in the session state and then using [Response.Redirect](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirect).

Answer (score 0):

Use a redirect:

C# code (put this in Page_Load or something):

```
Response.Redirect("showSomething.aspx?&key=fixed");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the URL from the status bar your link, use the onclick event to open the URL:

```
a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location='showSomething.aspx?id=11&key=fixed'"
```

Hope it helps you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the id in the session and then redirect to `showSomething.aspx?key=fixed`. then `showSomething.aspx?key=fixed` will read the session and file the id=11 and show it.